# Redirect deep links with changing values to homepage in wix

Tags: redirect, deep-linking, velo

I want to redirect a deep link like this: [https://www.mywixsite.com/lessons/{id}](https://www.mywixsite.com/lessons/%7Bid%7D)
to my wix site homepage (not in the error page where it redirects now).

The id value in the url is different every time, as the deep link changes. How can I achieve redirection to the homepage from the above url for every different id?

Wix gives you the option through the dashboard to redirect specific urls like https://www.mywixsite.com/lessons to another page, but what happens when the url includes a value that is changing every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [wix-router](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-router/introduction) to catch `lessons/{id}` requests and redirect to the home page.

1. Create the *lessons* router ([here is how](https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-creating-a-router#add-a-router))
2. Add the following code to the routers.js file (which created for you in the last step)

```js
export function lessons_Router(request) {
   const id = request.path[0];
   return redirect(`https://www.mywixsite.com?id=${id}`);
}
```

It will redirect the user from *https://www.mywixsite.com/lessons/1* to *https://www.mywixsite.com/?id=1* so you can identify from what lesson id the user came from.
If you don't need the id, you can remove it of course.

[Example website](https://moshef9.wixsite.com/route-to-home/lessons/1)

Comment: Thank you so much! That was what I needed.